# How to stop 30s timeouts in MAMP?

Tags: php, apache, mamp, http-status-code-500, mamp-pro

I am running WordPress code (to import 25 posts) that trips a 500 server error (reported via ajax) after 30 seconds, but the process continues on the server in the background.

For the life of me, I cannot find any evidence of a 30-seconds setting...

php7.4.33.ini...

```
max_execution_time = 1300
max_input_time = 3000
memory_limit = 512M
```

apache_error.log is showing pairs of these...

```
[Sat Apr 22 14:41:31.336668 2023] [fastcgi:error] [pid 10888] [client ::1:59639] FastCGI: comm with server "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php7.4.33.fcgi" aborted: idle timeout (30 sec)
[Sat Apr 22 14:41:31.391265 2023] [fastcgi:error] [pid 10888] [client ::1:59639] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php7.4.33.fcgi"
```

... though I'm not sure is strictly limited to the 500 events.

This is in Apache's httpd.conf...

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    # URIs that begin with /fcgi-bin/, are found in /var/www/fcgi-bin/
    Alias /fcgi-bin/ "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/"

    # Anything in here is handled as a "dynamic" server if not defined as "static" or "external"
    <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/">
        SetHandler fastcgi-script
        Options +ExecCGI
    </Directory>

    # Anything with one of these extensions is handled as a "dynamic" server if not defined as
    # "static" or "external". Note: "dynamic" servers require ExecCGI to be on in their directory.
    AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi .fpl
    
    MAMP_ActionPhpCgi_MAMP
    FastCgiIpcDir /Applications/MAMP/Library/logs/fastcgi
    MAMP_FastCgiServer_MAMP

    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        SetEnvIf Authorization "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

`max_execution_time` and `max_input_time` are not in .htaccess

I added...

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_value max_execution_time 300
    php_value max_input_time 300
</IfModule>
```

... but it didn't change (though I can't confirm if I have the php5 module).

Adding this...

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    FcgidIdleTimeout 600
    FcgidProcessLifeTime 600
</IfModule>
```

... and this...

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    FcgidIdleTimeout 300
    FcgidProcessLifeTime 3600
    FcgidMaxProcesses 128
    FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 8
    FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0
    FcgidConnectTimeout 300
    FcgidIOTimeout 300
</IfModule>
```

... also didn't change it.

Comment: After amending the php.ini, make sure  you restart apache to make it effective

Comment: @KenLee The php.ini settings I showed are not new additions, they have been there for some time. It seems like they are being ignored.

Comment: Create a new PHP file that only contains `<?php phpinfo();` and save it under your document root. Then access it directly in your browser and check what it says under max execution time. If that shows your configured timeout, then you need to check if there's anything in your applications code that overrides the max execution time (like `ini_set('max_execution_time', '30');` or `set_time_limit(30);`).

Comment: "but the process continues on the server in the background" - are you sure about this? Usually, that's why the error is thrown in the first place: because the max execution time was exceeded and the process is killed

Answer (score 2):

I believe I found answer for your question.

Just modify the line to state shown bellow and it should be working for you.

```
MAMP_FastCgiServer_MAMP -idle-timeout 3600
```

It's really weird that MAMP doesn't have setting for this.